# How to make ScrollView transparent?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles, android-scrollview

I have a ScrollView that contains a ConstraintLayout. The ConstraintLayout has a drawable resource as its background: `android:background=@drawable/bg_rounded_corner_pin_bg` which sucessfully gives the ConstraintLayout rounded corners. The issue I have is that the ScrollView shows up behind the rounded corners of the ConstraintView and I cannot make the ScrollView transparent:

Here's the layout file:

activity_enterpin.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>       
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:id="@+id/scrollviewPin"
    android:background="#00000000" // this is where I need transparency
    >

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:maxWidth="@dimen/layout_maxwidth"
        android:padding="@dimen/layout_padding"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_corner_pin_bg">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/title_margintop"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/pinlock_title"
            android:textColor="@color/text_title"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_title"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.example.isaacmain3.lockscreen.andrognito.pinlockview.IndicatorDots
            android:id="@+id/indicator_dots"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/dot_margintop"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/attempts"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/attempts_margintop"
            android:textColor="@color/text_attempts"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/indicator_dots" />

        <com.example.isaacmain3.lockscreen.andrognito.pinlockview.PinLockView
            android:id="@+id/pinlockView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/lockview_margin"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/attempts"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.1" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This is what the result looks like at the moment:

[image]

I've played around with the background color in the ScrollView and I am able to successfully change the color to any non-transparent color from the field I commented above. How do I get rid of these corners?

Here's the drawable file that I used to make rounded corners in case that's of any use:

bg_rounded_corner_pin_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

  <!--  <stroke android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#999999"/>-->

  <!--  <padding android:left="2dp"
        android:top="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:bottom="2dp"/>-->

    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:topRightRadius="20dp"
        />
</shape>
```

Comment: It's an activity being used as a dialog through the use of the android theme "Theme.Holo.Dialog"

Comment: try this 'android:background="@android:color/transparent"'

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the background, use

android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@null"

Answer (score 0):

Define a new theme in `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="TransparentActivity" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg_rounded_corner_pin_bg</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
</style>
```

Then, in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity android:name=".<activity_name>"
        android:theme="@style/TransparentActivity"/>
```

Finally, in the activity class:

```
DisplayMetrics m = new DisplayMetrics();
getDisplay().getMetrics(m);

WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
params.width = m.widthPixels*4/5;
params.height = m.heightPixels*3/4;
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
getWindow().setAttributes(params);

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
....
```

Note that there is code *before* `super.onCreate()` is called.

Comment: Thanks!! Simply using <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item> where "color/transparent" is #00000000 worked for me!!!